# .NET Core many-to-many query

Tags: asp.net-core, many-to-many, asp.net-identity, relationship

I have a many to many realtionship between a Project-model an a user. I'm trying to display all projects in which the logged in user is a member of, but I can't really get it right.

**User Model**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }
}
```

**Project Model**

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }

}
```

**UserProject Model**

```
public class UserProject
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to write the query in SQL like this but it doesn't work

```
        AppUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        var q = (from e in context.Projects
                  join t in context.UserProjects on e.ProjectId equals t.ProjectId
                  where t.UserId == user.Id
                  select e.ProjectName);
```

I have managed to write a query to get all the projects by an id and all it's members like this

```
        var project = context.Projects
            .Where(x => x.ProjectId == id)
            .Include(x => x.UserProjects)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.AppUser)
            .First();
```

But I don't manage to get all the projects a user is a member of. I appriciate any help I can get, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the projects a user is a member of like :

```
 var userID = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Type== ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

 var projects = _context.Users
    .Where(p => p.Id == userID)
    .SelectMany(p => p.UserProjects)
    .Select(pc => pc.Project).ToList() ;
```

In a many-to-many relationship :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProject>()
        .HasKey(pc => new { pc.UserId, pc.ProjectId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProject>()
        .HasOne(pc => pc.AppUser)
        .WithMany(p => p.UserProjects)
        .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProject>()
        .HasOne(pc => pc.Project)
        .WithMany(c => c.UserProjects)
        .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.ProjectId);
}
```